# convert coffeescript to js -> reworking classes to avoid initClass

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, coffeescript

trying to rework converted from coffee-script file to js file.

I have the following decaffeinated code :

```
/*
 * decaffeinate suggestions:
 * DS102: Remove unnecessary code created because of implicit returns
 * DS206: Consider reworking classes to avoid initClass
 * Full docs: https://github.com/decaffeinate/decaffeinate/blob/master/docs/suggestions.md
 */
angular.module("resources").factory("AdminTerritory", [
  "RailsResource",
  function (RailsResource) {
    let AdminTerritory;
    return (AdminTerritory = (function () {
      AdminTerritory = class AdminTerritory extends RailsResource {
        static initClass() {
          this.configure({
            url: Routes.admin_territories_path(),
            name: "territory",
            pluralName: "territories",
            interceptors: ["IndexMetadataInterceptor"],
          });
        }
      };
      AdminTerritory.initClass();
      return AdminTerritory;
    })());
  },
]);
```

I want to avoid initClass, but not sure how to do it...

id did the following but it does not work

```
AdminTerritory = class AdminTerritory extends RailsResource {
        constructor() {
          super();
          this.configure({
            url: Routes.admin_territories_path(),
            name: "territory",
            pluralName: "territories",
            interceptors: ["IndexMetadataInterceptor"],
          });
        }
      };
      return AdminTerritory;
```

updated: added CoffeeScript file

```
angular.module('resources').factory 'AdminTerritory', ['RailsResource', (RailsResource) ->
  class AdminTerritory extends RailsResource
    @configure {
      url: Routes.admin_territories_path()
      name: 'territory'
      pluralName: 'territories'
      interceptors: ['IndexMetadataInterceptor']
    }
]
```

Comment: If you want to fix the CoffeeScript code, please post that as well.

Comment: You seem to be looking for `AdminTerritory.configure({…});`.

Comment: it does not work (Error: this.config is undefined). 
all code is working except that one if i refactor to use ->
 constructor() { super() instead static initClass;

Comment: i added coffeescript

Answer (score 1):

Adding AdminTerritory.configure({}) outside of class and constructor worked fo me

```
angular.module("resources").factory("AdminTerritory", [
  "RailsResource",
  function (RailsResource) {
    let AdminTerritory;
    return (AdminTerritory = (function () {
      AdminTerritory = class AdminTerritory extends RailsResource {
        constructor() {
          super();
        }
      };
      AdminTerritory.configure({
        url: Routes.admin_territories_path(),
        name: "territory",
        pluralName: "territories",
        interceptors: ["IndexMetadataInterceptor"],
      });
      return AdminTerritory;
    })());
  },
]);
```